# VBSCRIPT Search Copy and Paste

Tags: vbscript

I have a list of 4000+ files I need to sort through and Copy. Does any one know a script that I can paste a list of file names and select a file location and have it copy the desired files and paste them in a designated file location?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which OS windows,mac,linux?

Answer (score 0):

You can browse thru the Microsoft Technet Scripting Center repository [here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B0%5D.Value=VBS&f%5B0%5D.Text=VB%20Script).

What you seem to want to do is easily scriptable, but "paste" and "select" are GUI actions
not appropriate in a scripting context.